# Aiogram3: How to change a group into a supergroup?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I want to restrict the sending of messages by the user according to a given condition. The *restrict* method only works with respect to a supergroup. Can I change the type?

I noticed that after restricting the user through the telegram interface, the group itself changes the type. But after calling the restrict method, an error occurs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.